# Could not find or load main class

Tags: java

[image: Imagem caputada do Netbeans 8.1,]

Tento executar meu projecto o NetBeans 8.1 e da este erro mostrado na imagem inserida, tenho java e todos seus compontes ja instalados, o erro surgio apos negar executar um form, dando informacoes de erro de memoria e de seguida ja nao executa o projecto todo

Comment: Você esqueceu de colocar o método `main` na sua classe.

Comment: As class que tenho são simplesmente pra fazer o control ou são de controle e já verifiquei tenho o método Main. Estou a trabalhar com a GUI. E este erro surgiu apos eu inserir imagens como fundo do form

Comment: e quando clico no erro mosta o seguinte codigo:         <java classpath="${classpath-translated}" classname="${classname}" dir="${work.dir}" jvm="${platform.java}" fork="true" failonerror="${java.failonerror}">